# Need help in building a simple circuit using transistor

Tags: led, transistors, resistors

[image]I am new to EE.

I am trying to figure out a circuit. I need to make use of resistors,a BC547 and a LED. I am using a 9V power supply. Can you recommend a circuit schematic that uses only the components specified above?.This circuit should light up the LED

I edited the post.This time I posted the diagram. I don't know if it is right but this is what I saw.Please let me know if it works.

Comment: Seriously, do you expect us to say anything sensible with just this information? Give us the circuit diagram (this site has a circuit editor, or draw it on paper and add a photo). As it is  you are asking something like "I want to make this food. It has eggs, butter, flour and sugar in it. How much sugar do I need?"

Comment: Please also choose a good title for your question.

Comment: You edited your question, but I still don't see any circuit diagram, or - failing that -, a description of what you want to achieve. Without any requirements for your circuit you could as well just spread them out on your table. PS in your previous version there was a relay, did it disappear?

Comment: What should the circuit do?

Comment: Someone edited my question. Sorry man I'm new to this site and i dont know the basics. My professor just list these parts for ua to build. He didnt even explain how these parts work

Comment: The led should simply light up

Comment: @allenjohnson, in that case no transistor is needed. Just use the 9 V battery, LED, and a resistor with around 700 ohms value.

Comment: but we're required to use all of the parts given. and the LED is 5mm

Comment: As shown transistor is NPN (emitter to bat-). You MUST have a base to V+ resistor. Without this bad things will happen.

Comment: OK. So you are in course where you are expected to make a circuit without any prior explanation or pointers to explanation? In that case quit it and go to a decent course/school/university or whatever.

Comment: If the goal is just to light up the LED you can leave out the transistor. When your teacher insist on using the transistor: connect all three legs to the same random point in your circuit. That should teach him to formulate a better assignment.

Comment: What are the chances that you are intended to produce an uncompensated constant current source for the LED using the transistor and a few resistors? Like the first one on this link: http://www.radio-electronics.com/info/circuits/transistor/active-constant-current-source.php

Answer (score 1):

I understand that your teacher wants you to use the transistor as a switch to light up the LED.You must add a resistor between the base and the positive supply or the transistor will be destroyed by too much internal heat.Other than that,it can work well if you choose the right resistors(let me know if you need help calculating their values) and LED.